# Db pattern for finding the owner of a record

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, orm

I'm looking for a pattern for dealing with a situation where a record in a table may be related to 1 and only one of several other records and I need to know which.  It's difficult to describe so I will use an example with an oauth client from a recent project.

A client has an id and secret and teams or users may own clients

```
clients
client_id|client_secret

user_clients
user_id|client_id

team_clients
team_id|client_id
```

The issue here is when someone attempts to use client credentials to get an access token I need to know if those credentials belong to a team or a user. I'm not really sure of the best way to deal with this, I control the database so changes can be made.

Some options I've considered:

```
Modify clients and remove user_clients and team clients

clients
client_id|client_secret|team_id(nullable)|user_id(nullable)
```

```
Create a client owners table and remove user_clients and team_clients

client_owners
team_id(nullable)|user_id(nullable)|client_id
```

```
Adding a type to the clients table and doing 2 queries or a conditional query

clients
client_id|client_secret|type(user or team)
```

```
Left joins and filtering/mapping in code.

select * from clients c left join user_clients u ... left join team_clients t ... where c.client_id = ?
```

None of these options feel great so I am wondering if there is a better pattern.  This is a simplified example, sometimes these objects are much more complicated and have many more possible relationships so the queries can get pretty hairy and also difficult to manage when using an orm (though requiring raw sql for parts of the system is not an issue).

I'd love to hear how people are solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As to ORMs: There is a reason for people calling these "obfuscation layers" jokingly. They try to present your data hierarchically, while it actually is relational. This means with an ORM there will almost always be issues and compromises. At least in my experience. ORMs will be able to deal with "a client can be owned by a user" and "a client can be owned by a team". Whether they understand that a client can only be owned by *either* a user *or* a team is another question, but maybe they don't really have to. I don't see using an ORM hence as a point to consider in your database design.

Comment: I agree on the ORM thing.  I wouldn't sacrifice data integrity for the sake of the ORM and I rarely use them in read contexts except for fast prototyping.  But all other considerations being equal I would take the option that is ORM friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Design

What you describe are 1:n relations:

- One user can own multiple clients
- One team can own multiple clients

So, the first approach seams appropriate: The client table has a user column and a client column.

Now you say a client can only be owned by *either* a user *or* a client. You would have a check contraint on the client table for this to ensure that only one of the IDs is set. (And if every client *must*  have an owner, this constraint would also care about this.)

### Some example queries

If you want to get all clients owned by users:

```
select * from clients where user_id is not null;
```

If you want to know whether a client is owned by a user or a team:

```
select
  c.*,
  case when user_id is not null then 'user' 
       when team_id is not null then 'team' 
                                else 'none'
  end as owner
from clients c;
```

If you want user or team information:

```
select c.*, coalesce(u.name, t.name) as owner_name
from clients c
left join users u on u.user_id = c.user_id
left join teams t on t.team_id = c.team_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a thoughtful response.  Looks like I have been flagged for not providing enough information, though I thought I had.  It's been helpful to hear an outside perspective, I'm working in isolation at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The idea with the left joins is something you can go with. Leave your `clients` table with just `clientID` and left join it on `user_clients` and `team_clients`.

You could also combine that with your first option and add a column for `user_clientsID` and `team_clientsID` and at adding to the left join `clients.user_clientsID <> 0` which is going to help you with the.

The 2nd and 3rd option is something I have seen used as well. With the second option perhaps being the one that can sometimes create the most headaches.

Also an option you can consider is creating a view table with all the information you might need